# Basics of Lie 2-algebras?

Tags: category-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, higher-category-theory

Could somebody (simply) explain the basics foundations of Lie 2-algebras, and some basic practical applications ?

For instance, does it exist a 3-map (equivalent to the 2-map commutator for Lie algebras), with :

$$ [T_a, T_b, T_c] = f_{abc}^d T_d $$

Comment: What you describe is not a Lie 2-algebra, it is a Lie triple system (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_system#Lie_triple_systems). A Baez-Crans Lie 2-algebra is a Lie algebra internal to the category of 2-term chain complexes.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: Thanks. Is there any relation between the two (Lie triple system and Lie 2-algebra) ?